# HTTP Post not working

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, web-service

I am wanting to POST some data from Arduino to WebService (written in .NET), intending to save some temperature data to MS SQL Server.

My code in arduino is:

```
void PostarDados(String dados, String chamador) {
  if (client.connect("mysite.com.br",80)) {
    client.println(chamador);
    client.println(F("Host: mysite.com.br"));
    client.println(F("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    client.print(F("Content-Length: "));
    client.println(dados.length());
    client.println();
    client.println(dados);
  }
  if (client.connected()) client.stop();
}
```

When sending to Serial instead of client, I am obtaining the following text:

```
POST /webservice.asmx/SetValoresTempUmidade HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.com.br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 39

Chave=1&Temperatura=23.30&Umidade=42.20
```

I have enabled HTTP POST in web.config to make HTTP POST possible (I can successfully invoke webservice from browser):

```
  <location path="Webservice.asmx">
    <system.web>
      <webServices>
        <protocols>
          <add name="HttpGet"/>
          <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have also set `ScriptMethod` to my webservice functions:

```
<WebMethod()> <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)>
Public Sub SetValoresTempUmidade(Chave As Integer, ByVal Temperatura As Double, ByVal Umidade As Double)
    Dim ctx As New DataClassesDataContext
    Try
        Dim A As New TBL_DADO
        A.CHAVE_INICIO = Chave
        A.DATA = Now
        A.TEMPERATURA = Temperatura
        A.UMIDADE = Umidade
        ctx.TBL_DADOs.InsertOnSubmit(A)
        ctx.SubmitChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Finally, I am trying to get some response from server using the following code (not receiving anything):

```
while (client.connected()) {
  while (client.available()) {
   buffer[counter++] = client.read();
  }
}
```

Explained that, I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How could I debug this?

Comment: I think PostarDados() is missing to \r\n\r\n at the end of the HTTP message

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work

Comment: You're hiding any errors  in your webservice method as there is nothing between your `Catch` and `End Try`. My first action would be to add logging in there to see if anything is going wrong there.

Comment: I would also try to code up a simple GET request webservice - just to simplify things and to make sure the requests are getting to the webservice at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
byte server[] = {XX, XX, XX, XX}; //IP
if (client.connect(server,80)) {
```

instead of

```
if (client.connect("mysite.com.br",80)) {
```

worked